# использование random в массивах С++

Tags: c++, массивы, случайные-числа, char

Как из массива данных типа char вывести случайные пары элементов, чтобы те не повторялись?
Уже сделал работающую программу для вывода этих рандомных пар, но они повторяются.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

const char* a1[6] = { "ABC","ACB","BCA","BAC","CAB","CBA" };

srand(time(nullptr));

int c = 6;
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    cout << a1[rand() % c] << " - " << a1[rand() % c] << endl;
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Возьмите просто abс и скормите это в std::next_permutation, не используйте ранд - это не энтропия а просто функция y(t), есть std::mt

Comment: я начал изучать с++ пару недель назад и не совсем понимаю, как это должно выглядеть, простите, если спрашиваю банальные вещи

Comment: Что именно Вы хотите сделать, какой вывод вы ожидаете ?

Comment: Не повторялись *пары*, *элементы в праре* или просто *элементы*? Последнее при требуемом их количестве невозможно :)

Comment: можно создать объект mt19937 (mersenne twister) он более рандомный

Comment: Случайные пары элементов (т.е., элементы случайной последовательности) не могут с гарантией не повторяться. Можно говорить о генерации случайной последовательности пар элементов с последующим выводом неповторяющихся пар.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const char* a1[6] = {"ABC", "ACB", "BCA", "BAC", "CAB", "CBA"}; // слова
int c = 6, j = 0, r, s, f;
int num[60];    // рабочий массив для хранения индексов напечатанных слов
for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) num[i] = 0;
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

random_device rd;   // генератор сл.чисел
mt19937 gen(rd());
uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0,5);   // сл.числа в нормированном диапазоне от 0 до 5
while (j < 60) {
    r = dist(gen);
    do {
      s = dist(gen);
    } while(s == r);    // слова в паре не должны повторяться

    f = 1;    // флажок уникальной пары слов
    if(j > 0) // если это не первая пара, ищем ее среди напечатанных
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k += 2)
            if(r == num[k] && s == num[k+1]) {  // если новая пара слов найдена среди напечатанных
                f = 0;  // сбросить флаг уникальной пары
                break;
            }
    if(f == 1) { // если новая пара слов уникальна, сохраним индексы слов в массиве и печатаем
        num[j] = r;
        num[j+1] = s;
        cout << a1[r] << " - " << a1[s] << "  " << (j+2)/2 << endl;
        j += 2;
    }
}
cout << "Число размещений из 6 по 2 = " << j/2 << endl;         //  6!/(6-2)! = 30
return 0;
}
```

Замечание: Для корректной компиляции в Code::Blocks необходима включенная опция
 -std=c++11. Это вызвано использованием продвинутого генератора случайных чисел.

Comment: это какой-то си стайл решение)

Comment: Автор вопроса, как начинающий, исходит пока из известного ему набора понятий. Потому и решение ограничено в средствах. На самом деле,  важнее, что вопрос его сформулирован неоднозначно, не в терминах комбинаторики. Например, в случае сочетаний без повторений решение было бы другим.

Comment: Все равно много лишней писанины в Вашем варианте

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. Я пытался гуглить как включить -std=c++11, понял только то, что куда-то нужно прописать CONFIG += C++11, так и не разобрался куда, надеюсь это не слишком глупый вопрос.
На счет моей задачи - мне нужно было вывести случайную пару для 6 элементов, чтобы второй выводимый элемент в строке не повторялся.
пример  - 
ABC - ACB;
ACB - BCA;
BCA - ABC;
BAC - CBA;
CAB - BAC;
CBA - CAB;

Comment: Мне неизвестна ваша среда программирования, а я использовал Code::Blocks под Win7. И для этого компилятора указанная опция (поддержка стандарта ISO c++11) по умолчанию выключена. Включается через меню Настройки/Compiler/Флаги компилятора (3-я строка). Но в действительности, вместо этого для генерации случайных чисел вы можете пользоваться функциями srand()  и rand(), как и ранее. На результат это принципиально не влияет. Тогда и опцию включать незачем.

Comment: Кстати, в приведенном вами примере не повторяются не только элементы в паре, но и отсутствуют одинаковые пары. Именно такой результат я стремился получить. Для повторяющихся пар (ABC-ACB, ...,ABC-ACB, ...) всё проще. Рабочий массив и контроль одинаковых пар не требуются.

Comment: Я использую Visual Studio 19, я так понимаю, что эта опция включена там по умолчанию. Ещё раз спасибо вам за помощь.

Comment: GeraItLUL: Если ваша проблема решена, пожалуйста, поставьте галочку "Ответ принят" для выбранного ответа.

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю Вам решить задачу таким путем

next_permutation создаст вам набор перечислений без повторений.

Дальше мешайте контейнер и выводи сколько надо уникальных комбинаций

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

int main() {
    std::vector<char> char_array{'a', 'b', 'c'};
    std::vector<std::string> comb;

    do {
        comb.push_back(std::accumulate(std::begin(char_array), std::end(char_array), std::string{""}));
    } while (std::next_permutation(std::begin(char_array), std::end(char_array)));

    std::size_t count_print{2};
    if (count_print > comb.size()) {
        throw std::out_of_range ("...");
    }

    std::shuffle(std::begin(comb), std::end(comb), std::mt19937_64{std::random_device{}()});

    auto n{count_print};

    auto it{std::begin(comb)};

    while (n) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
        it = std::next(it);
        --n;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Просто, но если требуется неповторений в паре, а не вообще:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    size_t j1 = rand() % c,
        j2 = j1;
    while (j2 == j1)
        j2 = rand() % c;
    cout << a1[j1] << " - " << a1[j2] << endl;
}
```